# How can I capture all the values of the dropdown list in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a dropdown box that displays the list of States. There are around 40 States in the list.
Every time when I scroll down the list, the List displays only 15 to 20 States at a time.

I want to capture all the values of the list and save them in the string array. And then check alphabet sorting.

How can I do it using Cypress? Currently, It captures only the top 15 items from the list.

This is my code:

```ts
const verifySortOrdering = (key: string) =>
  getSingleSelectList(key).then(dropdown => {

    cy.wrap(dropdown).click();

    if (dropdown.length > 0) {

      const selector = 'nz-option-container nz-option-item';
      let NumOfScroll = 1;
      const unsortedItems: string[] = [];
      const sortedItems: string[] = [];

      cy.get(selector).then((listItem) => {
        
        while (NumOfScroll < 7) {
          sortAndCheck(selector, unsortedItems, sortedItems);

          if (listItem.length < 15) {
            break;
          }
          NumOfScroll++;
        }

      });
    }
  });


const sortAndCheck = (selector: string, unsortedItems: any, sortedItems: any) => {

  cy.get(selector).each((listItem, index) => {
    if (index === 15) {
      cy.wrap(listItem).trigger('mousedown').scrollIntoView().last();
    }
    unsortedItems.push(listItem.text());   
    sortedItems = unsortedItems.sort();
    expect(unsortedItems, 'Items are sorted').to.deep.equal(sortedItems);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example based off of what you provided. Added an additional check to ensure the list has the right amount of options. You may or may not want that. Deep copying the unsorted list so it doesn't get sorted due to a shallow copy. Added validations after the unsortedItems list gets built so we can validate once instead of for every item in the list.

```
var unsortedItems = new Array()
var expectedListCount = 32
cy.get('#myselect>option').should('have.length', expectedListCount)
.each(($el) => {
    unsortedItems.push($el.text());
}).then(() => {
    var sortedItems = [...unsortedItems]; // deep copy
    sortedItems.sort();
    expect(unsortedItems).to.deep.equal(sortedItems)
})
```

Another example based on your revised sample but I can't verify it without having a working example of your DDL. This builds up the unsortedItem list first and then does the comparison.

```
const verifySortOrdering = (key: string) =>
  getSingleSelectList(key).then(dropdown => {
    cy.wrap(dropdown).click();
    if (dropdown.length > 0) {
      const selector = 'nz-option-container nz-option-item';
      let NumOfScroll = 1;
      const unsortedItems: string[] = [];
      const sortedItems: string[] = [];
      cy.get(selector).then((listItem) => {
        while (NumOfScroll < 7) {
          unsortedListBuilder (selector, unsortedItems, sortedItems);
          if (listItem.length < 15) {
            break;
          }

          NumOfScroll++;
        }
      });
    
      var sortedItems = [...unsortedItems];
      sortedItems.sort();
      expect(unsortedItems).to.deep.equal(sortedItems);
    }
  });

const unsortedListBuilder = (selector: string, unsortedItems: any, sortedItems: any) => {
  cy.get(selector).each((listItem, index) => {
    if (index === 15) {
      cy.wrap(listItem).trigger('mousedown').scrollIntoView().last();
    }
    unsortedItems.push(listItem.text());   
  });
};
```

Comment: The problem I am having here is that the entire states are not displayed to the DOM. The more I scrolled down to the list, the States that were displayed in the beginning do not get displayed any more.

Comment: I see. You would need to create a closure structure that grabs the values, scrolls, and repeats as needed to build up the unsortedItems list before moving on. Do you have a working example that I could look at? Perhaps there are examples available based on the tech you are using (i.e. react-select)?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Gray, I updated my code above. This code works for the list that has less than 15 items.

Comment: Do you want to verify the sort order of all items combined in one list or do you want to verify them by scroll group? The title of your question suggests all but your test workflow validates by groups.

As an example, if you have list groupings like this: (abc<scroll>, abd<scroll>, ajz), your test will pass because each set you're validating is ordered correctly within it's subset. If you were to add all those to a single list and then sort so it looks like this: 'aaabbcdjz', the test would fail because it doesn't match the unsorted list which would look like this: 'abcabdajz'.

Comment: I want to verify the sort order of all items combined in one list

Comment: I added a revised example to my original post. See if that helps. Tough to know if it will work or not without being able to test against that specific DDL. Primary takeaway is to not do your comparisons per scroll but after you've built up the unsorted list.

Comment: var sortedItems = [...unsortedItems]; This [...unsortedItems] returns empty value. THat 's why I put sort inside the 'SortAndCheck' function